# Access a .NET 4.5 class library in .NET4.0 winform

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

Is there anyway to reference a .NET4.5 class library in a .NET4.0 WinForm application?

I tried just adding the reference as per usual i.e. Right click on referenced under the .Net4.0 win form app and then add the library in but it gives me the following error

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'LibTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Both are loaded within the same solution and build otherwise without error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot.** .Net frameworks are not forward compatible. They are backward compatible , you can use .Net framework 3.5 assembly in 4.0, but you can't use 4.5 assembly in .Net framework 4.0

See: [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you have access to source code of 4.5 assembly you can try compiling it with target framework set to 4.0, if there isn't anything used specifically from 4.5 it will compile successfully and could be used with your current project.

Comment: As I thought. I can't do so since the Lib uses 4.5 features

Comment: @const_ref, is there any specific reason that you can't upgrade your current project to 4.5 ? Are you targeting windows XP ?

Comment: The original form is fairly old and targets multiple platforms so its not easy to change. Its not really a big deal, would just of been nice if possible.

Comment: @const_ref, no my friend, I am afraid its not possible. You have to upgrade your current project to 4.5